# How to access Django manage.py with Docker Compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am using Django as my Web-Framework.
As a database I use PostgresSQL.
To start my Postgres Database and the Webserver I use Docker.

When I start the server and db with docker-compose up, everything works fine. The database loads properly into Django and I dont get any errors.

But when I run for example `python3 manange.py makemigrations` django throws an error:

> could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Where "db" is the name of my postgres database.
This is even then when server and database are running on a different window. What I find very weird is that the Database is found when I start with docker.

How do I access commands like `python3 manage.py [...]`?

So for example I need to create a superuser and dont know where to create that because if I use the normal `python3 manage.py createsuperuser` I get the same error as above.

The console window from starting docker I also cannot use because there the Django Server runs and just displays the incoming http posts and requests.

Comment: [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) It may help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use [`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) to run the management command within your app container.

```
docker-compose exec webservicenamehere python manage.py makemigrations
```

(Refer to `docker-compose ps` or your compose YAML for `webservicenamehere`.)

You're getting that `db` error because the hostname `db` is only a thing within the Docker network that Docker Compose gives you; your host machine is not aware of such a hostname (and the database isn't directly exposed to the host machine anyway unless you say it should be).

Comment: I am sorry to bother you. But where exactly can I find my Webcontainer Name?

Comment: `docker-compose ps`

Comment: @AKX By default, webcontainernamehere  != servicename. docker-compose exec expects service name.

Comment: I found it its just he same given in the docker-compose.yml as a heading

Answer (score 1):

You can [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) a new container matching a template in your `docker-compose.yml` file, but with a different command and other settings.

```sh
docker-compose run djangoapp \
  ./manage.py createsuperuser
```

This has two notable advantages over `docker-compose exec`.  You can only use `exec` on a container that's running, but `run` creates a new container; if your application can't start until it runs its initial migrations, you need `run`.  Some complex setups do things like set up environment variables in an entrypoint script, and `exec` will not see these, but `run` will.